# Problem property name where an optimal solution in a graph can be used as a solution in any subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, optimization

Suppose one is given a graph optimization problem where the optimal solution $S$ for the problem on graph $G$ can be used as a solution for any subgraph of $G$. In other words, given $S$ is an optimal solution for the problem on $G$, then $S \wedge G_i$ is a solution on $G_i$ all $G_i \subseteq G$. Is there a canonical name for this property for a graph optimization problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **master solution** for an instance of a combinatorial problem is a solution with the property that it is optimal for any sub instance.
$~$

> Martijn van Ee, René Sitters:
>   On the Complexity of Master Problems.
>   Proceedings of MFCS-2015, LNCS 9235, pp 567-576
>   https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-48054-0_47

$~$

> Deineko, V.G., Rudolf, R., Woeginger, G.J.:
>   Sometimes travelling is easy: The master tour problem.
>   SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics 11, 1998, pp 81–93.
>   https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S0895480195281878

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not in fact need something quite as strong as this however. I only need the property that any optimal solution in the original graph is a solution in the subgraph (it doesn't necessarily need to be the optimal solution in the subgraph). If there is a *different* term for this property, great. Otherwise, I'll checkmark this answer in a few days.